# Lisp Scheme : let to lambda

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, let

I am new to Lisp Scheme. I came across this code which uses "let".How do I replace it with lambda

Here is the code

```
    (define Gen-Decoder-A
      (lambda (p)
        (define check-decode
          (lambda (n) 
            (num-valid-words (encode-p p (encode-n n))))
          )
        (let ((decode-compare (map check-decode abc-nums)))
          (encode-n (get-position (apply max decode-compare) decode-compare)))
        ((lambda 
        )
      )
```

Here is the link to the full code : https://github.com/corypisano/CS314/blob/master/Project2/decode.ss

The let  is in Gen-Decoder-A
Help me change let to lambda

Answer (score 3):

A `let` is just syntactic sugar for a `lambda` - the `let`variables can be rewritten as `lambda` parameters that get bound when calling the `lambda`. For example, this expression:

```
(let ((decode-compare (map check-decode abc-nums)))
  (encode-n (get-position (apply max decode-compare) decode-compare)))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
((lambda (decode-compare)
  (encode-n (get-position (apply max decode-compare) decode-compare)))
 (map check-decode abc-nums))
```